# What happens when using child constructor with type of parent in c#? Parent x = new Child();

Tags: c#, inheritance

Someone sometimes when creating an instance of parent class uses child constructor like:

```
Parent x = new Child();
```

In this kind of instantiation, x object only access to the Parent property and method and can not access to any member of Child class only members that declare with virtual keyword and are override in the Child class!

My question is: is this instantiation of object have any performance issues?

What happens exactly when using this way fo instantiate object?

I can't find in Microsoft documentation.
I watched a video course about Design Patterns and the teacher in section of SOLID Principle said that this way of using virtual and override keywords is the way to get rid of violations of Liskov substitution.

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: Let me ask you counter question. Why do you think its performance issue?

Comment: "is this instantiation of object have any performance issues?" compared to what? This questions assumes there is any alternative that provides the same functionality but runs faster. So what functionality you´re after?

Comment: [Obligatory link to Eric Lippert's performance rant blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: The type of the variable that an expression is assigned to has no impact at all on how constructors are called. `Child x = new Child()` invokes exactly the same code. Much has been written on the differences between virtual and non-virtual methods; that's a different matter that need not be rehashed here.

Comment: becouse when trying to instantiate with Parent constactor , compiler error says "An explicit conversion need"!! 
is that mean in the first way the compiler implicity convert Child to parent?
and conversion always has performance issue @HimBromBeere

Comment: when i trying

 Child x = new Parent();
 compiler error hapens

Comment: Every `Child` instance is also a `Parent` instance, but the reverse is not true, which is why `Child x = new Parent()` cannot compile. Nor is it true that "conversion always has [a] performance issue". Many conversions are, from the point of view of the runtime, free, since they involve reinterpreting a reference. The type of the variable the reference is stored (partially) determines how the method calls are dispatched.

Comment: " is this instantiation of object have any performance issues"? No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is quite generic, so I am going to approach this in a similar way.

To state this shortly, and if I get this right, you are searching what is going on when you are doing:

```
BaseClass obj = new DerivedClass();
```

Assuming that `DerivedClass` extends `BaseClass`.

This is very commonly used as an [Object-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) concept, as it is one of the basic traits of [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).
You declare a parent class variable, and assign a derived class object instantiation.

If this sounds strange to you, think it in terms of inheritance:
A `DerivedClass` object, is practically also a `BaseClass` object.
To put it simply: A Truck, a Car and a Bike are also Vechicles.
So, in practice, you can use `BaseClass` variable to point to a `DerivedClass` object.

Using the `obj` variable from that point on, the compiler will not normally (I put aside any kind of tools or specific optimizations and stick to the basics) "know"
that the obj mostly "derived" class is "DerivedClass". Check this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-inheritance-in-constructors/) for more.

This is because this is determined at [run-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)), providing some capabilities. For instance, any overriden method implementations etc. in derived class will now be determined at run-time, following a concept named [Late Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). Therefore,
calling `obj.myDerivedMethod()` (existing inside both the derived and base classes, with different implementations) will invoke the mostly derived type method implementation.

This way, you achieve the evaluation and determination of a number of things at Runtime, without needing to know everything beforehand.

Mentioning "Performance", the answer is "It Depends". What do you want to do?

In general, actions executed at run-time contrary to compile-time are costly in terms of execution time, resources etc, talking in general. On the other hand, usually this is followed by a number of optimisations, and you are following the OOP paradigm, leading to cleaner code, more close to the real world paradigm (and again, [this is under discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120019/whats-the-benefit-of-object-oriented-programming-over-procedural-programming), as this is not the only modern programming paradigm).

Causing "issues", is not the way I would think about it though. This is a paradigm well supported, not only by C#, but also by almost all Object-Oriented languages, such as Java, C++ etc. There are many things you can mistakenly do on this to "cause performance issues", but I do not see an issue by instantiating a derived class instance to a base class variable, OOP-wise.